# Add class to element if there is a attribute in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How to I add a class to a div element when it has a 'style' attribute containing variable data?

```
    <div style="background-color: #000;">
    </div>
```

What I want to achieve is a script that automatically adds a class `post-with-bg` to every div element with the above properties.

Comment: Do you want this to work only for divs with bg color #000, or all divs with *any* background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the following [selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/): `div[style="background-color: #000;"]`

```
$('div[style="background-color: #000;"]').addClass('post-with-bg');
```

UPDATE: 
If you want to target all divs that have a background set via the `style` attribute, not just a black background, use the following instead:

```
$('div[style*="background-color"').addClass('post-with-bg');
```

Comment: Note that this won't select elements such as `<div style="background-color: #000; font-weight: bold;">`. Or `<div style="background-color:#000;">` for that matter (without the space). This may not be a problem, we don't know exactly what OP wants and why, but relying on the direct string representation of an element's style often has its disadvantages.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div[style*="background-color: #000"]').addClass('post-with-bg');
});
```

Comment: Although this is the right basic technique, I'm not convinced he wants #000 specified (rather any div with a background)

Comment: If Jon Story is correct, this can easily be fixed of course, by just looking for `background-color`. But if OP is indeed asking for exactly this, then it shoudl be noted tha this won't match `background-color:#000` or `background-color: rgb(0,0,0)` for instance.

Comment: Yes he wants to "add a class post-with-bg to every div element with the above properties"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()`:

```
$("div").filter(function () {
  return $(this).attr("style") != "";
}).addClass("post-with-bg");
```

But this will add literally all the `<div>`s with the class. So it is better that you need to select a parent this way:

```
$(".affect-these div").filter(function () {
  return $(this).attr("style") != "";
}).addClass("post-with-bg");
```

Answer (score 1):

This gets all divs in the HTML and checks if the color is `#000`. If it is, then adds the class `post-with-bg`

```
$('div').each(function() {
    if($(this).css('background-color') == "rgb(0, 0, 0)")
      $(this).addClass("post-with-bg");
});
```

Comment: +1 This looks at computed style, so it will work for any div with a black background, regardless of whether that is derived from a style attribute, or  a separate stylesheet. Which may or may not be what OP wants.

Comment: Yes I know. I guess the question has different interpretations, until OP modifies or clarifies it